# Motherboard went up in flames

Tags: motherboard

I just recently purchased the ECS A55F2-M3, FM2 Motherboard.

I have a couple pictures to show you:

[image]

[image]

I think it is a voltage regulator that had went up in flames.

My questions are:

- What caused this to happen?
- Could this have happened because of my power supply (only a 220W stock HP PSU) or was this a manufacturing defect?
- What will I have to do? Buy a new motherboard?

Comment: My guess is a manufacturing defect caused a short between the layers of the PCB.

Comment: wierdly the voltage regulator *looks* fine. They don't even look singed.

Comment: My dad cleaned off the burned areas to clear it up a little more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## What cause?

I acutally suspect the protective paint covering the middle leg has impurities, maybe some metalic fragment or even dirt mixed from air flow, during the manufacturing process.

It may not has problem during testing phrase in factory, but accumulated too much heat during actual use.

It can be seen from the photo that the paint cover was almost completely gone while not much damage to the chip. There is a small burn mark on the corner of the chip but that is from the fire of the burning paint.

The chip packaging is intact. So the chip did not burn itself.

## Related to PSU?

Really doubt. This is motherboard manufacturing defect.

## Buy a new mother board?

You do need a replacement. Contact your seller and arrange RMA shipment. You may have to pay for one-way (not both ways) shipment. The whole process can from 2 weeks to 2 months(there is no standard and depends on situation). You have to confirm that with your seller.

If you are in a hurry to build the machine, then yes, you may have to buy an extra board.

Comment: Well you gave me a wonderful answer, thank you so much, and some of the burn marks arent there because we cleaned it off a little with paper towel to get a better look, but other than that, you answered 100%, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If this is a new motherboard, it must be a manufacturing defect. An underpowered PSU shouldn't cause damage to the motherboard, and no matter how overpowered one might be, the motherboard will only draw as much current that it needs.

I would contact ECS for a replacement. Hopefully it is under warranty.

Comment: Perhaps too little or too much power headroom is not itself a problem, but a poorly regulated PSU can harm other components in the system, and most PSUs only regulate well within the specified range of loads.

Comment: I am actually thinking of going with an Asus motherboard, but need to know if it will do better. The Asus is an A85X chipset. *edit* Guy up top said I should go with a Gigabyte, so ill look for one of those.

Comment: @BenVoigt That is true. However, unless the PSU catches fire itself, I doubt it would cause problems such as what was pictured. Poor power regulation can cause hardware failure, but I doubt it could cause the motherboard to catch fire.

Comment: A number of years ago, I had a properly-spec'd PSU that caused very similar damage to **three** motherboards (2 different manufacturers). The PSU itself appeared fine on the surface - no fire, no visible failure, but after replacing the PSU along with the last motherboard, I had no further problems.

Comment: @alroc I'm curious what kind of electronic defect in the PSU could cause such a thing, but I will defer to your experience, since it seems people are contesting my statement, anyway.

Comment: @Ben Richards - I'm not saying that it's impossible that it's strictly a motherboard defect. Just pointing out that it *is* possible for the PSU to cause motherboard components to fail. I don't feel it's appropriate to state that it's most likely *not* the PSU without evidence that the PSU is functioning properly - it really ought to be tested, else the new motherboard may suffer the same fate in the future.

Comment: @alroc Good point.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely not because of lack of wattage. I would rather bet on manufactured defect, ut it also would not surprise me if that was PSU's fault. In the end of the day, your warranty service should accept the motherboard as it is almost impossible to know whether it was burned on purpose, due to PSU or due to poor microschemes/conductors, etc.

Comment: I have a bunch a parts coming, new PSU, GPU, and I already have the A10 5700. Would you recommend me getting a new motherboard or get the replacement from ECS, because I will be playing a good bit of games on this system. If you need specs let me know. Because I did find an Asus motherboard, and want to know if that would do better than the ECS.

Comment: If you want a good motherboard, I would go for Intel products. However, they are not cheap. Next I would pick Gigabyte. Asus has never been a good motherboard manufacturer and for its "AsRock" is often regarded as "AssRock".

Comment: Well I do have a A10 5700 so I can not get an intel motherboard.

Comment: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128570 You think this motherboard will do me good.

Comment: Yes, it has more memory sockets, more expansion slots, has a more reasonable audio chipset and etc.

Comment: @Thomas: Don't get that one, the reviews are terrible.

Comment: I would get a replacement anyway. No use wasting a warranty and this is a seriously odd failure

Comment: @BenVoigt What motherboard would you suggest for me? I found this one but I am not sure. http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157342

Comment: @Thomas: While that one also has a couple 1-egg reviews, they're from the same person and it appears he, not the motherboard, is the problem.  I'm running an ASRock board myself (although one designed for Intel CPUs) with no trouble at all.  So I think it's a good choice.

Comment: Asrock used to be asus' budget brand before they were spun off. Their current boards seem ok when I asked around. I had quite a few that lasted about a decade or more Pre retirement